# Вывод изображения на страницу сайта по относительному пути из модели ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

В папке wwwroot есть папка images, где хранятся изображения (для модели `User` изображения в папке users, для `Clothes` в папке clothes и т.д.). В классе User есть свойство `ImageGuid`, куда загружается GUID изображения из БД. Я хочу, чтобы в свойстве `ImageSrc` хранился относительный путь к изображению модели, чтобы в html я мог просто прописать `<image src="@Model.ImageSrc"/>` и у меня вывелось соответствующее изображение.

Класс User

```
[Table("Users")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Column("Image")]
        public Guid? ImageGuid { get; set; }

        public string ImageSrc => ImageGuid == null ? "~/images/default.jpg" : $"~../images/users/{ImageGuid}.jpg";

        public virtual ICollection<Clothes> ClothesSellers { get; set; }
        
    }
```

HTML разметка

```
@model User;


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>User/Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h3>@Model.UserId - @Model.UserName</h3>
    <p>@Model.Email</p>
    
    <img src="@Model.ImageSrc"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Структура wwwroot]

Comment: И? Вы не задали вопрос. Что-то не получается?

Comment: [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0) - на всякий случай полезная ссылка.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov изображение не выводится

Answer (score 0):

Нужно убрать знак `~` в пути изображения у свойства ImageSrc.
В итоге, если определить свойство так:

```
public string ImageSrc => ImageGuid == null ? "/images/default.jpg" : $"/images/users/{ImageGuid}.jpg";
```

то изображение будет корректно отображаться на странице